# What is the use of referencing appState/rootState in feature store

Tags: ngrx

Trying to understand the ngrx example app, got stuck and unable to figure out its use case.

What is the importance of **State** in the below code taken from [ngrx-example-app](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/projects/example-app/src/app/books/reducers/index.ts)

```
export interface State extends fromRoot.State {
  [booksFeatureKey]: BooksState;
}

/** Provide reducer in AoT-compilation happy way */
export function reducers(state: BooksState | undefined, action: Action) {
  return combineReducers({
    [fromSearch.searchFeatureKey]: fromSearch.reducer,
    [fromBooks.booksFeatureKey]: fromBooks.reducer,
    [fromCollection.collectionFeatureKey]: fromCollection.reducer,
  })(state, action);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing this has no run-time differences, it's only to make typescript aware you "have" a root state.

This is needed to make typescript happy if you access root state or root selectors from within your feature state selectors.